# Is there any Zend2 library that provides filesystem abstraction layer?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm looking for something similar to: http://knplabs.com/blog/give-your-projects-a-gaufrette
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette), I do it too (even in ZF2 projects)!

```sh
php composer.phar require knplabs/gaufrette:0.1.*
```

You can then use it anywhere in your application and eventually use it as a service by defining it in your `YourNamespace\Module#getServiceConfig`:

```php
namespace YourNamespace;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Gaufrette\Filesystem;
use Gaufrette\Adapter\Local as LocalFs;

class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'your_namespace' => array(
                'filesystem' => array(
                    'base_path' => 'data/files',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'YourNamespace\Filesystem' => function (ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) {
                    $config   = $sl->get('Config');
                    $basePath = $config['your_namespace']['filesystem']['base_path'];

                    return new Filesystem(new LocalFs($basePath, true));
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

You can then use service `YourNamespace\Filesystem` across all your application.

I also use it in conjunction with `Symfony\Filesystem` to handle file moving/copying/checking operations. Not everything must come from Zend Framework 2 to be used in a ZF2 application.